# how to create relational select option ajax in laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to create a relational select option in laravel 8 using ajax but didn't work I get this error in the console: 405  Method Not Allowed
POST [http://127.0.0.1:8000/decomptes/%7B%7B%20route(%20'getOperationsChantier'%20)%20%7D%7D](http://127.0.0.1:8000/decomptes/%7B%7B%20route(%20%27getOperationsChantier%27%20)%20%7D%7D) 405 (Method Not Allowed)

the route

```
Route::post('/getOperationsChantier', [DecompteController::class, 'getOperationsChantier'])->name('getOperationsChantier');
```

the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// When an option is changed, search the above for matching choices

    $('#chantiers').change(function(){
        $("#mySelect option").remove();
      //  $("#city option").remove();
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           url : "{{ route( 'getOperationsChantier' ) }}",
           data: {
             "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
             "id": id
             },
           type: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function( result )
           {
                $.each( result, function(k, v) {
                     $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {value:k, text:v}));
                });
           },
           error: function()
          {
              //handle errors
              alert('error...');
          }
        });
}).change();
```

});

the function in the controller :

```
function getOperationsChantier( Request $request )
    {
      $this->validate( $request, [ 'id' => 'required|exists:chantiers,id' ] );
      $chantierOperations = ChantierOperation::where('chantier_id', $request->get('id') )->get();
      $output = [];
      foreach( $chantierOperations as $chantierOperation )
      {
         $output[$chantierOperation->id] = $chantierOperation->operation_id;
      }
      return $output;
    }
```

can someone help me this is the first time when I use ajax

Comment: Step one is clear route cache. Also you should properly escape values before putting them into Javascript from PHP. Do this for your URL: `url : @json(route('getOperationsChantier')),`

Comment: Check if caching the routes works.

Comment: this solution : url : @json(route('getOperationsChantier')), didn't work show me that message in javascript file  Expression expected.ts(1109)